# Building HTTrack fails with checking for SSL_CTX_new in -lssl..anks!. no configure: error: not available

Tags: software-installation, compiling

Trying to scrape the contents of my old website, whose login details I have long forgotten (ancient and long defunct ISP, but whose servers appear now to be run by someone else).  Came across a recommendation for HTTrack, so downloaded, and tried to build.  The standard GNU-style `./configure` gave me:

```
checking for SSL_CTX_new in -lssl..anks!. no
configure: error: not available
```

Can anyone please tell me what packages I might need to install to make this build work?!

Comment: Could you please add a little more detail? What *exactly* did you do, what did you want to expect to happen and what happened instead? Did you encounter any warning or error messages? Please reproduce them in their entirety in your question. You can select, copy and paste terminal content and most dialogue messages in Ubuntu. Please **[edit]** your post to add information instead of posting a comment. (see [How do I ask a good question?](/help/how-to-ask))

Answer (score 2):

I'm sorry, but why you don't want to install binary package with
`sudo apt-get install webhttrack`?

It is available in [all releases since Trusty Tahr (14.04)](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&searchon=names&keywords=webhttrack).

If you want to build it from source you should enable deb-src sources, run
`sudo apt-get build-dep webhttrack` and so on.

Comment: Thanks - didn't know there was such a package.  All good now!

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
sudo apt-get install libssl-dev
```